# Is it possible to create a PR on private repo whenever a different Go based public repo has a latest release, with Github Actions?

Tags: github, github-actions

So at present on private repo we do have zcn.wasm file which is built as :

```
git clone https://github.com/0chain/gosdk
cd gosdk
CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=js GOARCH=wasm go build -o ../private-repo/public/zcn.wasm  ./wasmsdk
```

This happens as a manual process on users local. So each time a new gosdk version is there UI needs to check that manually and update the file on private repo public dir and sometimes the private repo might break when we miss the train.
What about firing a PR on private repo with build zcn.wasm file whenever the new public repo ( gosdk ) is released ?

Comment: Yes it's possible. What did you try so far ? Can you share your current workflow - where you have exact problems ?

Comment: @GrzegorzKrukowski googled the specific problem and was not able to find a suitable reference. Can you help me with some references or blog post addressing the similar problem or leading to solve the given specific problem ?